# Window A/C Remote Temperature Sensor

Tags: air-conditioning

I have an [LG LW1217ERSM 12,000 BTU window A/C unit](https://www.lg.com/us/air-conditioners/lg-LW1217ERSM-window-air-conditioner) and was wondering if it is possible to connect a remote temperature sensor to the unit.

For example, the unit is set to 72 degrees but the temperature in another room is 80 degrees. With the remote temperature sensor placed in the 80 degree room, the unit would continue to cool until that room is also brought down to 72 degrees. Unfortunately this unit does not seem to have this feature so I was wondering if it is possible to modify the unit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is it **possible** - probably.

Is it **practical** - probably not. Start with voiding the warranty and work up from there. The odds of ruining the thing so it does not work any more are not insignificant, depending how it's constructed and your personal skills.

Is it *far simpler* to just set the unit to 66 or 64 degrees, if that's what it takes to get the other room down to 72 - yes.

Can you perhaps *assist the process* by adding a fan between rooms to help circulate the air - Yes, and *that might reduce the amount you have to overcool the first room* to get the second room cool enough.